# Pyrit CPU benchmark in vmware much faster than on host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, wpa, backtrack-linux

Can anyone explain me...
why on guest ubuntu, cpu is faster than on host ubuntu... with 'pyrit benchmark'

System:
CPU: i7 3770 (HyperThreading Enabled)
RAM: 24Gb
GPU: Nvidia GTX 650 Ti Boost

I have a dualboot:

Windows 7 & ubuntu 12.04 lts

on Windows 7 installed vmware workstation 10, and guest os ubuntu 12.04 (the same as secondary boot).

Running "pyrit benchmark" command on both systems. **Using only CPU** (GPU driver is not installed)

On VMware Guest Ubuntu, i get about **617 PMKs/s * 8 cores ~ 4700-4900 PMKs/s**

and on Host (secondary boot) Ubuntu i get about **213-250 PMKs/s per core ~ 1700 PMKs/s**

Why?

And how can i get these rates in host Ubuntu? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know but your peformance is dismal on both..

My cheap Athlon 640 X4 should get about 1/2 the performance of your I7 3770...but its averaging about 99% of your results.

Try A live linux distro with pyrit , just to see if there is something wrong with your ubuntu install?

#1: 'CUDA-Device #1 'GeForce GT 240'': 5169.6 PMKs/s (RTT 2.6)
  #2: 'CPU-Core (SSE2)': 595.4 PMKs/s (RTT 2.8)
  #3: 'CPU-Core (SSE2)': 618.9 PMKs/s (RTT 3.0)
  #4: 'CPU-Core (SSE2)': 625.9 PMKs/s (RTT 2.9)
  #5: 'Network-Clients': 0.0 PMKs/s (RTT 0.0)

Comment: Thank you. 
There was an issue with CPU Multiplier in BIOS setup. They was set to 16 instead 38.